# English translation of R’ Bachya on Sefaria

Tags: commentaries, internet, translation

Regarding the English translation of Rabbenu Bachya’s commentary on Chumash, how much of the English translation was uploaded to the Sefaria site? I see that the introduction to Bereshis was left untranslated.

<sup>PS. This question was asked by another user who then left the site.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I asked your question to the Sefaria team. Here is their answer

> The translation of Rabbeinu Bahya on Sefaria is nearly complete. The
>   digital files we received were missing the intro and start of
>   Bereshit. We were unable to get hold of a physical copy.
>
> We will be happy to upload the missing text if we get hold of it.